# Date in the x-axis - OCTAVE

Tags: datetime, octave

I am trying to plot an array (Dst) from the excel file against date/time (UT) in the x-axis. The octave does convert the date-time into a value - serial number.

I tried converting the UT into a string and cell string. However, I can't plot the UT since the class type has changed into cell and character.

What can I do?

Here is my code:

```
%exporting data from the excel file
UT = data(1:120,7:7)
Dst = data(1:120,9:9)

%exporting UT as a string.
pkg load financial
Date = x2mdate(Date,0);
str = datestr(Date, 15);
A = cellstr(str);


%plotting
plot (Date, Dst); datetick('x',15)

error: plot: no data to plot
```

Comment: Hi Jayson, your question as it is now is unlikely to get any answers, since UT and Dst could be anything. Can you replace them in this snippet with a short example of the kind of data that would demonstrate your problem, please? Ideally something that I could copy/paste in an octave terminal to show the problem.